# beforeSave() error in PHP while move_uploaded_file error in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, php

I am uploading an image from Android to a php server. The file uploads correctly , but when I try to move the file to another directory, it gives an error. I am using CakePHP in WAMP on Win7. I have set file_uploads = On in php.ini

**PHP code:**

```
if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)) {
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];       

//  base64 encoded utf-8 string     
    $binary=base64_decode($base);

//  binary, utf-8 bytes     
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    $filename = $this->request->data['name'];
    pr($filename);

    $folder_URL = 'C:\wamp\tmp\\' . $filename; 

    pr($folder_URL);

    $file = fopen($folder_URL, 'wb');

    //write to file
    fwrite($file, $binary);

    fclose($file);

    $url = 'C:\wamp\www\moccv\app\webroot\img\profile_pics\arora.jpg';
    $success = move_uploaded_file($folder_URL, $url);

    if ($success) {
        pr('image uploaded successfully');
    } else {
        pr('could not upload image');
        print_r(error_get_last());
    }

}
```

**Output -**

```
arora.jpg
C:\wamp\tmp\arora.jpg
could not upload image
Array( [type] => 2048 [message] => Declaration of SluggableBehavior::beforeSave() should be compatible with that of ModelBehavior::beforeSave() [file] => C:\wamp\www\moccv\app\Plugin\Sluggable\Model\Behavior\SluggableBehavior.php [line] => 23)
```

**PHP code: SluggableBehavior.php**

```
<?php
/* SVN FILE: $Id: sluggable.php 36 2007-11-26 15:10:14Z mgiglesias $ */

/**
 * Sluggable Behavior class file.
 *
 * @filesource
 * @author Mariano Iglesias
 * @link http://cake-syrup.sourceforge.net/ingredients/sluggable-behavior/
 * @version    $Revision: 36 $
 * @license    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
 * @package app
 * @subpackage app.models.behaviors
 */

/**
 * Model behavior to support generation of slugs for models.
 *
 * @package app
 * @subpackage app.models.behaviors
 */
class SluggableBehavior extends ModelBehavior
{
    /**
     * Contain settings indexed by model name.
     *
     * @var array
     * @access private
     */             
     var $__settings = array();

/**
 * Initiate behavior for the model using specified settings. Available settings:
 *
 * - label:     (array | string, optional) set to the field name that contains the
 *                 string from where to generate the slug, or a set of field names to
 *                 concatenate for generating the slug. DEFAULTS TO: title
 *
 * - slug:        (string, optional) name of the field name that holds generated slugs.
 *                 DEFAULTS TO: slug
 *
 * - separator:    (string, optional) separator character / string to use for replacing
 *                 non alphabetic characters in generated slug. DEFAULTS TO: -
 *
 * - length:    (integer, optional) maximum length the generated slug can have.
 *                 DEFAULTS TO: 100
 *
 * - overwrite: (boolean, optional) set to true if slugs should be re-generated when
 *                 updating an existing record. DEFAULTS TO: false
 *
 * @param object $Model Model using the behaviour
 * @param array $settings Settings to override for model.
 * @access public
 */
function setup(&$Model, $settings = array())
{
    $default = array('label' => array('title'), 'slug' => 'slug', 'separator' => '-', 'length' => 100, 'overwrite' => false, 'translation' => null);

    if (!isset($this->__settings[$Model->alias]))
    {
        $this->__settings[$Model->alias] = $default;
    }

    //$this->__settings[$Model->alias] = am($this->__settings[$Model->alias], ife(is_array($settings), $settings, array()));
    if ( is_array($settings) ) {
        $retSettings = $settings;
    } else {
        $retSettings = array();
    }
    //pr( $retSettings );

    $this->__settings[$Model->alias] = am(
        $this->__settings[$Model->alias],
        $retSettings
    );

}

/**
 * Run before a model is saved, used to set up slug for model.
 *
 * @param object $Model Model about to be saved.
 * @return boolean true if save should proceed, false otherwise
 * @access public
 */
function beforeSave(&$Model)
{
    $return = parent::beforeSave($Model);

    // Make label fields an array

    if (!is_array($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['label']))
    {
        $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['label'] = array($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['label']);
    }

    // Make sure all label fields are available

    foreach($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['label'] as $field)
    {
        if (!$Model->hasField($field))
        {
            return $return;
        }
    }

    // See if we should be generating a slug

    if ($Model->hasField($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug']) && ($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['overwrite'] || empty($Model->id)))
    {
        // Build label out of data in label fields, if available, or using a default slug otherwise

        $label = '';

        foreach($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['label'] as $field)
        {
            if (!empty($Model->data[$Model->alias][$field]))
            {
                if ( !empty($label) ) {
                    $prepend = ' ';
                } else {
                    $prepend = '';
                }
                $label .= $prepend . $Model->data[$Model->alias][$field];
            }
        }

        // Keep on going only if we've got something to slug

        if (!empty($label))
        {
            // Get the slug

            $slug = $this->__slug($label, $this->__settings[$Model->alias]);

            // Look for slugs that start with the same slug we've just generated

            $conditions = array($Model->alias . '.' . $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug'].' LIKE' => $slug . '%');

            if (!empty($Model->id))
            {
                $conditions[$Model->alias . '.' . $Model->primaryKey.' !='] = $Model->id;
            }

            $result = $Model->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields' => array($Model->primaryKey, $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug']), 'recursive' => -1));
            $sameUrls = null;

            if (!empty($result))
            {
                $sameUrls = Set::extract($result, '{n}.' . $Model->alias . '.' . $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug']);
            }

            // If we have collissions

            if (!empty($sameUrls))
            {
                $begginingSlug = $slug;
                $index = 1;

                // Attach an ending incremental number until we find a free slug

                while($index > 0)
                {
                    if (!in_array($begginingSlug . $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['separator'] . $index, $sameUrls))
                    {
                        $slug = $begginingSlug . $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['separator'] . $index;
                        $index = -1;
                    }

                    $index++;
                }
            }

            // Now set the slug as part of the model data to be saved, making sure that
            // we are on the white list of fields to be saved

            if (!empty($Model->whitelist) && !in_array($this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug'], $Model->whitelist))
            {
                $Model->whitelist[] = $this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug'];
            }

            $Model->data[$Model->alias][$this->__settings[$Model->alias]['slug']] = $slug;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

/**
 * Generate a slug for the given string using specified settings.
 *
 * @param string $string String from where to generate slug
 * @param array $settings Settings to use (looks for 'separator' and 'length')
 * @return string Slug for given string
 * @access private
 */
function __slug($string, $settings)
{
    if (!empty($settings['translation']) && is_array($settings['translation']))
    {
        // Run user-defined translation tables

        if (count($settings['translation']) >= 2 && count($settings['translation']) % 2 == 0)
        {
            for($i=0, $limiti=count($settings['translation']); $i < $limiti; $i+=2)
            {
                $from = $settings['translation'][$i];
                $to = $settings['translation'][$i + 1];

                if (is_string($from) && is_string($to))
                {
                    $string = strtr($string, $from, $to);
                }
                else
                {
                    $string = r($from, $to, $string);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (count($settings['translation']) == 1)
        {
            $string = strtr($string, $settings['translation'][0]);
        }

        $string = strtolower($string);
    }
    else if (!empty($settings['translation']) && is_string($settings['translation']) && in_array(strtolower($settings['translation']), array('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')))
    {
        // Run pre-defined translation tables

        $translations = array(
            'iso-8859-1' => array(
                chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
                .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
                .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
                .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
                .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
                .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
                .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
                .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
                .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
                .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255),
                'EfSZsz' . 'YcYuAAA' . 'AAACEEE' . 'EIIIINO' . 'OOOOOUU' . 'UUYaaaa' . 'aaceeee' . 'iiiinoo' . 'oooouuu' . 'uyy',
                array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254)),
                array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th')
            ),
            'utf-8' => array(
                array(
                    // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
                    chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
                    chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
                    chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
                    chr(195).chr(135) => 'C', chr(195).chr(136) => 'E',
                    chr(195).chr(137) => 'E', chr(195).chr(138) => 'E',
                    chr(195).chr(139) => 'E', chr(195).chr(140) => 'I',
                    chr(195).chr(141) => 'I', chr(195).chr(142) => 'I',
                    chr(195).chr(143) => 'I', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
                    chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
                    chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
                    chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
                    chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
                    chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
                    chr(195).chr(159) => 's', chr(195).chr(160) => 'a',
                    chr(195).chr(161) => 'a', chr(195).chr(162) => 'a',
                    chr(195).chr(163) => 'a', chr(195).chr(164) => 'a',
                    chr(195).chr(165) => 'a', chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
                    chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
                    chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
                    chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
                    chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
                    chr(195).chr(177) => 'n', chr(195).chr(178) => 'o',
                    chr(195).chr(179) => 'o', chr(195).chr(180) => 'o',
                    chr(195).chr(181) => 'o', chr(195).chr(182) => 'o',
                    chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(185) => 'u',
                    chr(195).chr(186) => 'u', chr(195).chr(187) => 'u',
                    chr(195).chr(188) => 'u', chr(195).chr(189) => 'y',
                    chr(195).chr(191) => 'y',
                    // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
                    chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
                    chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
                    chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
                    chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
                    chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
                    chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
                    chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
                    chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
                    chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
                    chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
                    chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
                    chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
                    chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
                    chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
                    chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
                    chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
                    chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
                    chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
                    chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
                    chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
                    chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
                    chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
                    chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
                    chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
                    chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
                    chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
                    chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
                    chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
                    chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
                    chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
                    chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
                    chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
                    chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
                    chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
                    chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
                    chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
                    chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
                    chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
                    chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
                    chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
                    chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
                    chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
                    chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
                    chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
                    chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
                    chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
                    chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
                    chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
                    chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
                    chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
                    chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
                    chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
                    chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
                    chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
                    chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
                    chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
                    chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
                    chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
                    chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
                    // Euro Sign
                    chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E'
                )
            )
        );

        return $this->__slug($string, am($settings, array('translation' => $translations[$settings['translation']])));
    }

    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]/i', $settings['separator'], $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($settings['separator']) . '[' . preg_quote($settings['separator']) . ']*/', $settings['separator'], $string);

    if (strlen($string) > $settings['length'])
    {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $settings['length']);
    }

    $string = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($settings['separator']) . '$/', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($settings['separator']) . '/', '', $string);

    return $string;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: <?php
if (!$success) {
    trigger_error("Error.", E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
use this code and edit your question.because it doesn't make sense for what error you receive.

Comment: or <?php print_r(error_get_last()); ?> use this to get what error u getting.

Comment: What's your remote server setup? Windows IIS, Apache, etc?

Comment: @DipeshParmar I have made changes and updated it with new error messages

Answer (score 0):

In which user are you running the web server?

Make sure that:

1. the path you are saving to is valid
2. the user running the `wamp` have permissions over that file

try changing the path to some simple path, maybe even relative paths, as well as changing the permissions over the target file to accessible to all users

Try to add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

to your page and check the apache error log for more info

**EDIT**

not sure that the error is related, try to mark the line

```
$success = move_uploaded_file($folder_URL, $url);
```

and check if the error still shows. The method signatures of the `SluggableBehavior` must be the same as those of the `ModelBehavior` class, meaning that the method signature of the `beforeSave()` method must be changed from:

```
function beforeSave(&$model)
```

to:

```
function beforeSave(Model $model)
```

Did you try to change the path and checked the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini file made below change.

```
file_uploads = On
```

if not then check for possible error that i mentioned in comments.
if still not then check for file upload size limitation.
if you are using cakephp then following code will surly help you.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($this->data['MODEL_NAME']['upload']['tmp_name']))
{
    $arr = explode('.',$this->data['MODEL_NAME']['upload']['name']);
    $image_name = time().".".$arr[1];

    $dest = APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.'other_file'.DS.$image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($this->data['MODEL_NAME']['upload']['tmp_name'],$dest);

    if(DO_CHECK)
    {
        /*****************code after success*****************/
    }
}
```

Comment: your model code is not properly written paste model code in question with C:\wamp\www\moccv\app\Plugin\Sluggable\Model\Behavior\SluggableBehavior.php this file code,

Comment: Uploaded SluggableBehavior File

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so I'm answering

I had some issues with uploading on CakePHP and it turned out to be 'post_max_size' limit in php.ini, might also want to check 'upload_max_filesize'. When you go over the limit there is no error message displayed in CakePHP and it drops part of your $this->request->data.

The error message is like @Kuf said, due to overriding the method beforeSave with a different signature. So changing parameter from &$model to Model $model should fix that.